# Error when using yq image in gitlab pipeline job

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, yq

I have a gitlab pipeline job that extracts the version number from a yaml file using yq tool and then exporting it as an environment variable. I am using mikefarah/yq:4.27.2 as a base image. the pipeline code is:

```
prepare-version:
  image: mikefarah/yq:4.27.2
  stage: prepare
  script:
   - ver=$(yq '.version' versions.yml)
   - echo "version=${ver}" >> version.env
artifacts:
   reports:
     dotenv: version.env
```

The pipeline always fails on:

```
Using docker image sha256:cecdbf2efcf7240d3378dd188844b2b5805420eef692dfb98aa3a1b6d366ef5a for mikefarah/yq:4.27.2 with digest mikefarah/yq@sha256:856f7ab12c58608d422a742a4917e6998ad065d9d48a5b1cd69c3ce8fa80f3fa ...
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -c
Usage:
yq eval [expression] [yaml_file1]... [flags]
Aliases:
  eval, e
Examples:
  # Reads field under the given path for each file
  yq e '.a.b' f1.yml f2.yml 
  # Prints out the file
  yq e sample.yaml
```

when using

> yq '.version' versions.yml

locally with the same yq version everything works fine. But in the pipeline it fails. Any Ideas why this happens?

Comment: `ver=$(yq e '.version' versions.yml)`

Comment: yeah, I tried that and also eval. still getting the same error. if no command is added by default it uses eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier to create my own Docker Image of yq since the documentation does not state why exactly this happens.

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17.0.7-alpine3.17

RUN wget https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/download/v4.34.1/yq_linux_amd64 -O /usr/bin/yq
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/yq
```

Answer (score 1):

I opted to use version 3 which worked without problems. I had to change the command then to

> yq r versions.yml 'version'

there seems to be a problem with the image of v4 even when trying this [issue solution](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/603)

Comment: It was easier to create my own Docker Image of yq since the documentation does not state why exactly this happens.

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
prepare-version:
  image: 
    name: mikefarah/yq:4
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: prepare
  ...
```

fix it.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**